# Не понимаю, к какому правилу относится точка с запятой

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, правила, точка-с-запятой

Не могу понять, почему в предложении стоит точка с запятой!
Правила читаю, но никак не соображу, к какому правилу данное предложение относится.

*В стану — перервать можно, как оса; глазюки черные, здоровющие, стригеть ими, как сатана, прости бог.* (М. А. Шолохов)

Comment: Точка с запятой — это проблема, но зачем цитировать здесь такой объём из учебника?

Answer (score 8):

**Это БСП, описание внешности состоит из двух отдельных тем.** Каждое предложение в составе БСП имеет собственные знаки препинания, структура предложений разная.

[Пунктуация. § 43. Запятая и точка с запятой в бессоюзном сложном предложении. / Розенталь: Справочник по русскому языку](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=149#pp149)

**Точка c запятой** ставится в бессоюзном сложном предложении, если предикативные части отдалены друг от друга по смыслу или значительно распространены и имеют внутри себя запятые.